# PHP login script should work but isnt

Tags: php

This is the same, very basic and amateur log-in script I used for a school project before. It worked fine then and still does on that site, but not on this new one Im doing. I know its not great at all, although its just annoying me now as it should be working.

It continues to say the password and ID are incorrect and directs me back, even if that is not the case.

Any help much appreciated.

Form:

```
<form action="adminlogin.php" method="POST">
ID:<input type="text" name="ID">
Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="login" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require ('login2.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
if (!$_POST['ID'] | !$_POST['password'])
{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('You did not complete all of the required fields')
    window.location.href='adminlogin.html'
    </SCRIPT>");
exit();
 }
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adminusers` WHERE 'ID' = '$ID' AND `password` = '$password'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Login Succesfully!.')
    window.location.href='adminview.html'
    </SCRIPT>");
exit();
}
else{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Wrong username password combination.Please re-enter.')
    window.location.href='adminlogin.html'
    </SCRIPT>");
exit();
}
}
else{
}
?>
```

PHP2

```
 <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "student") or die("mysql connection is failure.");
 mysql_select_db("curiositypizza") or die("Database does not exists.");
 ?>
```

Comment: `if (!$_POST['ID'] | !$_POST['password'])` is not valid

Comment: remove exit() , its terminate the application

Comment: @Daan - yes he should have to use !isset($_POST['ID'])

Comment: @MuhammadAli that doesn't matter because javascript redirects to another page.

Comment: What does `echo "SELECT * FROM \`adminusers\` WHERE 'ID' = '$ID' AND \`password\` = '$password'";` shows ?

Comment: @MuhammadAli `!` is a valid operator just `|` isn't instead he should use `||`

Comment: @Daan `|` is technically _valid_ ([bitwise OR](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)), it just probably isn't what the OP wants there.

Comment: but in php single pipe is not valid http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Comment: @PatrickQ It doesn't look neat.

Comment: @MuhammadAli Look at the PHP documentation w3schools sucks. Techhnically it is valid like patrick said.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause's column isn't being treated as a "column".

Comment: You're also storing passwords in plain text. **Believe me**, if this is a LIVE site, it's just a matter of time before you get hacked. **Just don't.** Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: usage of mysql_* functions not recommended. Instead you can use mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adminusers` WHERE 'ID' = '$ID' AND `password` = '$password'");
```

should be

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adminusers` WHERE `ID` = '$ID' AND `password` = '$password'");
```

The way you have it above will check for 'ID' = 'username', which will never be true, hence going to the else statement.

**UPDATE**

Although it is not the preferred method to do this, but will most likely get your script working until you refurbish it to a more cleaner piece of code.

Comment: Altough this query works. You shouldn't be teaching it like this way.

Comment: You open your query with double quotes but you attempt to escape your query using single quotes to put your variables in. Shouldn't it be:     `= '".$ID."'`

Comment: Appologies alex for being very poor at this, but I dont understand what you mean by saying it will check for username?

Comment: @GerardBritton currently your script has this: 'ID' = '$ID'. Note the same type of apostrophes. This will mean that SQL will try to compare (literally) ID with whatever the value of $ID holds. Unless you give ID exactly as a user id, it will never be true. Changing it to `ID` however will allow it to see `ID` as a column instead of a defined string. Hope I could make myself clear, apologies if not, the lack of sleep can interfere with my expressions...

Comment: Thanks a million alex, that did the trick! I understand now what you mean as well :)

Comment: You should use prepared statements instead of interpolation.